# URL Params split using Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the URL params for a page saved in a particular column as follows:

```
    Query_Params

    type=Outstanding%20Trade%20Ticket%20Report1&fileName=Outstanding%20Trade%20Ticket%20Report_3%20Mar%2014.xlsx
    type=Outstanding%20Trade%20Ticket%20Report2&fileName=Outstanding%20Trade%20Ticket%20Report_3%20Mar%2014.xlsx
```

I need to write an Oracle Query which returns the output in two columns as follows.

```
                Type                                                fileName

    Outstanding%20Trade%20Ticket%20Report1       Outstanding%20Trade%20Ticket%20Report_3%20Mar%2014.xlsx
    Outstanding%20Trade%20Ticket%20Report2       Outstanding%20Trade%20Ticket%20Report_3%20Mar%2014.xlsx
```

The application design is such that these two params can't be stored as 2 different columns while inserting the data.

I haven't been able to figure out the regex for the select statement.

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want results in two separate columns:

```
SQL> set define off;
SQL> SELECT regexp_substr('type=Outstanding%20Trade%20Ticket%20Report1&fileName=Outstanding%20Trade%20Ticket%20Report_3%20Mar%2014.xlsx', '^[^&]+') A,
  2  regexp_substr('type=Outstanding%20Trade%20Ticket%20Report1&fileName=Outstanding%20Trade%20Ticket%20Report_3%20Mar%2014.xlsx', 'fileName(.+)') b
  3  from dual;
```

Output

```
   | A                                           |B                                                                 |
   |---------------------------------------------|------------------------------------------------------------------|
   |type=Outstanding%20Trade%20Ticket%20Report1  | fileName=Outstanding%20Trade%20Ticket%20Report_3%20Mar%2014.xlsx |
```

Your Query will be

```
SQL> set define off;
SQL> SELECT regexp_substr(column_name, '^[^&]+') A,
  2  regexp_substr(columns_name, 'fileName(.+)') b
  3  from table_name;
```

Comment: Thanks so much, San. How can I strip out the words type= and filename= from the output in the same regexp? I could write the Regex on top of the returned output to split the same. `REGEXP_SUBSTR (fileType, '[^=]+', 1, 2)    AS fileType` but would be helpful if can be done in the same regular exp.